# How to get current date/time as a date object in PHP

Tags: php, date, datediff

How do you get today's date, as a date object?

I'm trying to compute the difference between some start date and today.  The following will not work, because `getdate()` returns an array and not a date object:

```
$today = getdate();           
$start = date_create('06/20/2012');
$diff = date_diff($start, $today);

echo($today . '<br/>' . $start . '<br/>' . $diff);
```

Output:

> Array ( [seconds] => 8 [minutes] => 1 [hours] => 16 [mday] => 11 [wday] => 1 [mon] => 6 [year] => 2012 [yday] => 162 [weekday] => Monday [month] => June [0] => 1339455668 )
>
> DateTime Object ( [date] => 2012-06-20 00:00:00 [timezone_type] => 3 [timezone] => America/Los_Angeles )

Answer (score 54, accepted):

```
new DateTime('now');
```

http://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.construct.php

Comparing is easy:

```
$today = new DateTime('now');
$newYear = new DateTime('2012-01-01');

if ($today > $newYear) {

}
```

**Op's edit**
I just needed to call *date_default_timezone_set*, and then this code worked for me.

Comment: I think the explicit `$today = new DateTime("now");` is more clear, even if the argument does default to "now".

Comment: The code *$today = new DateTime('now');* is actually throwing an error of some kind.  (500 internal server error)

Comment: @dbaseman Can you be more specific? What version of PHP are you running? http://codepad.org/5lYyo8MC

Comment: As of PHP 5.3.0, you can use the `diff` method that is part of the DateTime object. `$difference = $today->diff($start);`. This returns a DateInterval object and you can output the results several ways. https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.dateinterval.php

Answer (score 19):

To get difference in days use this:

```
$today = new DateTime('today');
```

the time in this object will be 00:00:00

If you want difference with hours minutes and seconds use this:

```
$now = new DateTime('now');
```

Comment: A very important distinction depending on use case.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using the *date_create* constructor (no parameter) to get the current date.

```
$diff = date_diff(date_create('06/20/2012'), date_create());
print_r($diff);
```

**Output:**

> DateInterval Object ( [y] => 0 [m] => 0 [d] => 8 [h] => 6 [i] => 30 [s] => 40 [invert] => 1 [days] => 8 )

I have no idea why, but Mike B's answer (and any constructor I tried for *DateTime*) threw an error for me in PHP5 / IIS.

Comment: Glad you found a solution. If you're curious to know why `DateTime` failed to instantiate you can try to turn up error reporting. 500 error is IIS's way of telling you that PHP barfed but it doesn't get much more specific. You can crank up the error reporting by placing these functions at the beginning of your script: `error_reporting(-1); ini_set('display_errors', 1); ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1);`. IIS's error log might also contain specific error messages.

Comment: @MikeB thanks.  This was the error:  *It is not safe to rely on the system's timezone settings. You are required to use the date.timezone setting or the date_default_timezone_set() function.*  Once I call *date_default_timezone_set*, your answer works.