# php: Error using new DateTime in PHP 5.3

Tags: php, datetime

I have some legacy code that was working for quite some time as follows:

```
$eventdate2 = new DateTime($eventdate);
```

However, my host changed the version of PHP I am using and since then it has not worked i.e. the code breaks at this point.

Unfortunately, I can't say what the old version of PHP was.  The host said they changed it back to the old version after I encountered a lot of other problems.  All I can say for sure is that the present version is 5.3 and that code is no longer working.

This answer suggests the above line should work but it no longer does for me.

[how to get current date/time as a date object in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10988625/how-to-get-current-date-time-as-a-date-object-in-php)

Can anyone suggest how to get this to work?

Comment: What value does the variable `$eventdate` contain? Btw, did I understand correctly that your host *upgraded to PHP 5.3*? That version has reached its end-of-life more than a year ago.

Comment: Do you get an error message?  And what is the value of $eventdate and $eventdate2 if you get that far?

Comment: if $eventdate is a DateTime object itself it won't work because DateTime expects a String

Comment: `DateTime` was introduced in 5.3, so you're definitely on the old version.

Comment: What is most likely is that when they switched you back to PHP5.3 they left error_reporting turned on and you are now seeing errors that were there all the time but you had not noticed before.

Comment: vardump shows string(5) "today"

Comment: try using 'now' instead of 'today'

Comment: Ok.  BTW, checking with <?php phpinfo() ?> version is 5.3.29. Code does not run with 'now' Does not show error message.

Comment: Looks like it may have worked in 5.2 and then again in 7 but not in 5.3.  Will have to find a workaround.  http://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.construct.php